# Staggered DiD -- Borusyak estimates way higher than Callaway&Sant'Anna, Sun&Abraham, Chaisemartin&d'Haultfoeuille

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, estimation

I am estimating a diff-in-diff in a staggered setup using the robust estimators mentioned in the title, all using the same data and setup (as far as possible). The results of 3/4 are **very** similar, however, the Borusyak estimates are substantially higher than any of those (between 50% and 100%). Pre-trends look fine and are very similar for all of those (incl. Borusyak).

In the data there is very likely substantial treatment effect heterogeneity just for background.

My questions are:
(1) is anyone aware of a particular reason why that might be?
(2) in the context of a paper, what would be a good way to investigate that (find observations that drive that, check for potential problems, violations, etc.)?

I cannot post the data unfortunately, but can try to provide synthetic data if useful.

Thank you!

- expected largely similar results
- re-checked model specifications

Comment: This doesn't seem like a programming question. If you have statistical questions, please ask at stats.stackexchange.com. If you want someone to review a reasonable amount of code, post the code at codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Sorry, you are probably right. Even if it's in R it's probably more statistical. I will do that!

Comment: Most of the time, if there's no code in your question it doesn't belong on Stack Overflow.